# Linear transformation for a rotation

Tags: matrices

I'm having trouble defining this linear tranformation. I understand the rotation around the origin is a linear transformation and I tested this using the 45 degrees rotation transformation T(x,y) = (x-y, x+y)

But I'm having trouble defining the expression for this linear transformation with a general angle (an so, the matrix). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since we map $e_{1}$ to $\cos(\theta)e_{1} + \sin(\theta)e_{2} $ and
$ e_{2}$ to $-\sin(\theta)e_{1} + \cos (\theta)e_{2}$

We have;

\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos (\theta)     & -\sin(\theta)  \\
    \sin(\theta)      & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}